# Implementing multiple Progress.bar in react-native

Tags: react-native, statusbar, progress

I want to achieve the WhatsApp stories like effect, where the number of progress bars on top are equal to the number of stories.

I'm using react-native-progress/bar library to achieve this effect, but I'm finding a way that how can I run second progress bar when first ends.
    Actually progress of Progress.bar changes with the change of state.
    What is an efficient way to do this by using a single state?

Here is code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  image: {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
  },
});

export default class Example extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.animate();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: 0
    };
  }

  animate() {
    let progress = 0;
    this.setState({ progress });
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (progress > 1) {
        progress = 1;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else {
        progress += 0.01;
      }
      this.setState({ progress });
    }, 20)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}} >
        <Progress.Bar
          key={'0'}
          style={styles.progress}
          progress={this.state.progress}
          indeterminate={false}
        />
        <Progress.Bar
          key={'1'}
          style={styles.progress}
          progress={this.state.progress}
          indeterminate={false}
        />
       </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Qasim Idrees, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem does not seem to be related with Highcharts.

Comment: Actually I didn't get any response. I need urgent help, I wasn't getting more related tags